# Get non attached object with find API in JPA / EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I want to get a non-attached object with find.
Something similar to what I get from named query with the "eclipselink.read-only" hint.
Is there a way to do it, or I need to write a named query by id and use the hint?

Comment: like a detached object, the sort you get by calling _em.detach()_

Comment: When eclipse link loads an object it creates a clone so it can be compared to it before queries and sent to database if needed (in case it use the deffered change tracking policy). I want to avoid having this object in cache and cloning it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass query hints to your [find method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map)) allowing you to pass the "eclipseLink.read-only" hint:

```
HashMap props = new HashMap();
props.put("eclipselink.read-only", "True");
em.find(class, id, props);
```